# How to know class and Mapping class from HQL NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

My idea is that I want to know entity and mapping class from HQL query.
For example if I have.
User.cs for Entity
UserMap.cs for Mapping User.cs

```
where I query with HQL like this>
var hql = session.CreateQuery("FROM User");
```

How can I know that this query run against User.cs and UserMap.cs mapping.
This is because I want to prevent user for query some of entity.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Fix by myself after digging into NHibernate source code and  get the idea but wonder why no other has the same problem like me before.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        var plan = CreateQueryPlan("FROM User u JOIN u.Country c", false);
        //Check(plan.ReturnMetadata, false, true);
        foreach(var type in plan.ReturnMetadata.ReturnTypes)
        {
            Log.DebugFormat("name: {0}", type.Name);
        }
    }

    public IQueryPlan CreateQueryPlan(string hql, bool scalar)
    {
        var sessionFactory = (ISessionFactoryImplementor)SessionFactory.GetNHSessionFactory();
        var plan = sessionFactory.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(hql, false,
              new CollectionHelper.EmptyMapClass<string, IFilter>());
        return plan;
    }
```